# pixelsearch clicking in middle?

Tags: autoit

it mostly clicks only in side (which is the sides pixels of a square) any idea how can click the middle area inside of pixelsearch? heres what i done but it wont work

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5WA7.jpg]

```
$greenbox = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight, 0x00FF00)
If isArray($greenbox) then
newX := greenbox[0] + 25
newY := greenbox[1] + 25
MouseMove($newX[0],$newY[1], 0)
MouseClick("Left")
```

Comment: Try making an array with all the pixels that are of that color. Then get the x and y, of the first and last value. Calculate the difference between the two, half it and add it to the first value, then you should have your center point. Hope this helps.

Comment: The code above is full of error. Are you sure this is the code you are using?

Comment: $newX and $newY are not arrays!

Answer (score 2):

$NewX and $NewY are not Arrays.

Try like this :

```
MouseMove($newX,$newY, 0)
MouseClick("Left")
```

or simplest :

```
MouseClick("Left,$newX,$newY)
```